# storageclass.storage.k8s.io "standard" not found for pvc on bare metal Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I've created a `persistentVolumeClaim` on my custom Kubernetes cluster, however it seems to be stuck in pending...

Do I need to install/configure some additional something? OR is this functionality only available on GCP / AWS?

**pvc.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
metadata:
  name: testingchris
```

describe pvc:

```
Name:          testingchris
Namespace:     diyclientapps
StorageClass:  standard
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolumeClaim","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"testingchris","namespace":"diyclientapps"},"spec":{"accessModes"...
Finalizers:    []
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age               From                         Message
  ----     ------              ----              ----                         -------
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed  8s (x3 over 36s)  persistentvolume-controller  storageclass.storage.k8s.io "standard" not found
```

Comment: Hi, With persistent volume claimPVC, you need to have persistent volume (PV)  which can be done dynamically using storage class or directly using PV. [PV](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)

Comment: >storageclass.storage.k8s.io "standard" not found, you need to create storage class file.[Storage Class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/)

Comment: I just saw that you are running the cluster on your bare metal therefore, You need to have storage capability in your bare metal cluster.

Comment: Thanks mate, I'm so sleep deprived right now and you've been super helpful today answering all these questions!

Comment: No worries. Take rest. keep exploring.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PVC is just a Claim, a declaration of ones requirements for persistent storage.

For PVC to bind, a PV that is matching PVC requirements must show up, and that can happen in two ways : manual provisioning (adding a PV from ie. kubectl) or with [Dynamic Volume Provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/)

What you experience is that your current setup did not auto provision for your PVC

Answer (score 2):

In my case of hostPath PersistentVolume, "ACCESS MODES"  was different for PV & PVC. I had made them identical/same and it resolved my issue.

Comment: This was my issue as well. Thank you!